# What exactly is NT AUTHORITY\SELF?

Tags: windows, privileges

I'm trying to understand `NT AUTHORITY\SELF` account and the difference between this one and `Everyone`.

I tried to google for it, didn't find anything useful. I saw several application grants access to SELF and not sure if it's a bad practice.

Does anyone know?

Comment: look in [`AccessCheckByType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-accesscheckbytype) - *PrincipalSelfSid* parameter. and related in link [`SECURITY_PRINCIPAL_SELF_RID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/well-known-sids)